# Prepositions with the noun "attitude"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Here is a sentence from a CPE coursebook:

> *This is surprising, given that great differences often exist between the **attitudes** of parents and adolescents **on** such issues.*

As we can see the preposition "on" is used here. If we consult Oxford Dictionary

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/attitude

we will see that *to*, *towards*, *about*, and *on* are all in use.

My native friend from the US told me that: "I don't say attitude "to" or "on", the others are contextual" That doesn't tell us anything except for his own preferences.

My question: Is there any way to choose between "to/towards" and "on" with *attitude*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a native English speaker, *on* sounds awkward in this situation.

As pointed out by user3169, there are many other contexts in which *on* would be the best choice, e.g. *comment(s) on, books/chapters on, advice on*. Personally, however, I would rewrite your sentence:

> This is surprising, given that great differences often exist between the attitudes of parents and adolescents **toward** such issues.

The matter of whether to use *toward* or *towards* is an entirely separate one, but you can find a fairly exhaustive discussion [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/toward-towards-usage). I simply don't think the *s* is necessary because the next word begins with *s*.

I would use *about* in phrases like, *ideas about, books about, information about*, but not *attitudes about*. As for the difference between *to* and *towards*, it's analogous to the difference between *in* and *inside*. The latter is **less ambiguous** and linguistically **stronger**. Of course, however, there are many instances in which *to* is the most appropriate, such as *comparing apples to oranges*.

In essence, your decision should be based on **minimizing ambiguity** and using the strongest word **appropriate** for the context.

Hope this helps!